# Need to adjust buttons at some distance which are floating right

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I'm trying to keep buttons at some distance from right side of the page.
Can we do that without adding padding-right .
what would be the solution for it to make it responsive as well.

Thanks.

Comment: please share code what you have tried so far

Comment: Everytime you ask a question share the code on jsfiddle or codepen please.

Comment: <div class="parent">

<div class="right">

<input type="button" id="send" value="send">
<a href="#" id="forget" >forget</a>

</div>
    
    </div>

Answer (score 0):

Without code we can't help much but if I understand you you want to keep child away from parent's sides. There are few ways to do this. First is to add padding to parent.

```css
.parent {
    padding: 30px;
}
```

But I guess you don't want to do that

Next way is using flex

```css
.parent {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
```

This will spread every child left and right so that they have same free space on both sides.

You can also use `justify-content: space-between` or `justify-content: space-evenly`

You can find more on [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content) link.

I hope this helped you in a way. If it didn't please submit your code so far and then we can work out the way to make it.

Happy Coding

Comment: HTML CLODE: 
<div class="parent">

<div class="right">

<input type="button" id="send" value="send">
<a href="#" id="forget" >forget</a>

</div>
        </div>

Comment: .right {
           float: right;
    }
       #send {
    height: 42px;
    width:150px;
    color: black;
    font-size: 22px;
    letter-spacing: 1.0px;
    line-height: 27px;
    text-align: center;
    height: 42px;
    width:150px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin-right: 17px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#forget{
    height: 37px;
    width: 92px;
    color: black;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 1.1px;
  
/* margin-right: 175px; don't want to use this to put them some distance from right side bcs it's not responsive */
}